# How can I set a default value for a reference attribute?

Tags: android, android-xml, android-resources

I am supposed to extract and create reference for all the colors in my android xml components. And I am creating the values for those references in multiple themes. But my app crashes when a particular xml file is not associated with any theme(since, there won't be values for the references). So, how can I solve this issue. Is there any way to set the default values for the reference attributes?

I tried experimenting with android xml tags, but new errors are thrown.

Initially text color is '#000000' for any theme.

```
<!-- My text view tag -->
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#000000">
```

Now, the text color is decided based on the theme after extracting the reference as follows:

```
<!-- My text view tag -->
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="?myTextViewColor">
```

```
<!-- My reference tag -->
<attr name="myTextViewColor" format="color" />
```

```
<!-- My theme tag -->
<style name="MyTheme">
    <item name="myTextViewColor">#000000</item>
</style>
```

If my xml is not associated with any theme, it is unable to get the value for "myTextViewColor" reference and is crashing with the following error:
Binary XML file line #21: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class.

I want to create references for all my colors but don't want my app to crash if it is unable to find the reference value. Can I set a default value for the reference ??

Comment: Did you found any solution for this @Hrudhay ?

Comment: @Jimit, No. Explored different ways but found nothing helpful.